# Is there a way of filtering mongodb data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const users = await User.find();

if (!users)
      return res.status(404).json({ success: false, msg: "No user found" });

users.filter((u) => u._id !== req.user._id);
```

I don't want to select req.user._id when I get all of the users. When I use filter method, it doesn't work. It still includes req.user._id in the data. Is there a way to handle this in a short way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/)

```
await User.find({
  _id: {
    $ne: ObjectId(req.user._id.toString())
  }
})
```

or you can use [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) if you have multiple ids

```
await User.find({
  _id: {
    $nin: [ObjectId(req.user._id.toString())]
  }
})
```

Comment: `ObjectId(req.user._id.toString())` didn't work but when I typed `$ne: req.user._id` directly it worked. Mongo documentations was confusing for me. Thank you so much <3.